# How to send an email after validating form inputs in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, react-hooks

I want to send an email after validating form inputs.

[ContactMe Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NKqj.png)

This is the validation code using hooks :

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

toast.configure()


export default function Home() {
  const initialValues ={name: "",email: "",subject: "",message: ""};
  const [formValues,setFormValues]= useState(initialValues);
  const [formErrors,setFormErrors]= useState({});
  const [isSubmit,setIsSubmit]=useState(false);


  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({...formValues,[name]:value});
    setIsSubmit(true);
  
  };


    
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(formErrors);
  if(Object.keys(formErrors).length===0 && isSubmit){
    console.log(formValues);
  }
  },[formErrors,isSubmit,formValues])

  
const validate =(values)=>{
  const errors = {}
  const regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/i;
  if (!values.name){
    errors.name="Name is required!";
  }
  if (!values.email){
    errors.email="Email is required!";
  }else if (!regex.test(values.email)){
    errors.email="This is not a validate email!";
  }
  if (!values.subject){
    errors.subject="Subject is required!";
  }
  if (!values.message){
    errors.message="Message is required! i want to hear something from you ";
  }
  return errors;
};

  const handleSubmit= (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
  }
```

**This is sendEmail function using EmailJS:**

```
const sendEmail=(e)=>{
  
  

    emailjs.sendForm('gmail', 'template_xsouglfff',e.target, 'user_PGXC8IvmNYbSPd1oLk1gAayy')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
      toast('Your message has been successfully sent.i will contact you soon.',{autoClose:8000});
     
}
```

This is form code :

```
<div className="col-md-9  wow fadeInRight animated">
              <form className="contact-form"  onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      id="name"
                      placeholder="Name"
                      name="name"
                      value={formValues.name}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <p>{formErrors.name}</p>
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      className="form-control"
                      id="email"
                      placeholder="Email"
                      name="email"
                      value={formValues.email}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <p>{formErrors.email}</p>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      id="subject"
                      placeholder="Subject"
                      name="subject"
                      value={formValues.subject}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <p>{formErrors.subject}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <textarea
                      className="form-control"
                      id="message"
                      rows="25"
                      cols="10"
                      placeholder="  Message Texts..."
                      name="message"
                      value={formValues.message}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    ></textarea>
                    <p>{formErrors.message}</p>
                    <button
                      
                      className="btn btn-default submit-btn form_submit"
                    >
                      SEND MESSAGE
                    </button>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

so, I want to run the Sendmail function if there is no error and then reset the form.

I would be grateful if you could help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I validated my own form with React and emailjs, it should prove useful:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";
import styles from "./ContactMeForm.module.css";

// This function validates emails
const validateEmail = email => {
  const regex =
    /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return regex.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
};

export const ContactMeForm = () => {
  const form = useRef();

  const [enteredName, setEnteredName] = useState("");
  const [enteredNameIsValid, setEnteredNameIsValid] = useState(false);
  const [enteredNameTouched, setEnteredNameTouched] = useState(false);

  const nameInputIsInvalid = !enteredNameIsValid && enteredNameTouched;

  const [enteredEmail, setEnteredEmail] = useState("");
  const [enteredEmailIsValid, setEnteredEmailIsValid] = useState(false);
  const [enteredEmailTouched, setEnteredEmailTouched] = useState(false);

  const emailInputIsInvalid = !enteredEmailIsValid && enteredEmailTouched;

  const changeNameHandler = e => {
    setEnteredName(e.target.value);

    if (e.target.value.trim() !== "") {
      setEnteredNameIsValid(true);
    }
  };

  const nameInputBlurHandler = () => {
    setEnteredNameTouched(true);

    if (enteredName.trim() === "") {
      setEnteredNameIsValid(false);
      return;
    } else {
      setEnteredNameIsValid(true);
    }
  };

  const changeEmailHandler = e => {
    setEnteredEmail(e.target.value);

    if (validateEmail(e.target.value.trim() !== "")) {
      setEnteredEmailIsValid(true);
    }
  };

  const emailInputBlurHandler = () => {
    setEnteredEmailTouched(true);

    if (enteredEmail.trim() === "") {
      setEnteredEmailIsValid(false);
      return;
    } else {
      setEnteredEmailIsValid(true);
    }
  };

  const sendEmail = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setEnteredNameTouched(true);
    setEnteredEmailTouched(true);

    if (enteredName.trim() === "") {
      setEnteredNameIsValid(false);
      return;
    }
    if (enteredEmail.trim().length === "") {
      setEnteredEmailIsValid(false);
      return;
    }

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        "service_<yourserviceid>",
        "template_<yourtemplateid>",
        form.current,
        "user_<youruserid>"
      )
      .then(
        result => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );

    setEnteredName("");
    setEnteredEmail("");
  };

  const nameInputClasses = nameInputIsInvalid ? "invalid" : "";
  const emailInputClasses = emailInputIsInvalid ? "invalid" : "";

  return (
    <div className={styles["form-container"]}>
      <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail} className={styles.form}>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          className={styles[`${nameInputClasses}`]}
          value={enteredName}
          type="text"
          name="name"
          onChange={changeNameHandler}
          onBlur={nameInputBlurHandler}
        />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input
          className={styles[`${emailInputClasses}`]}
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={enteredEmail}
          onChange={changeEmailHandler}
          onBlur={emailInputBlurHandler}
        />
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" />
        <input className={styles.submit} type="submit" value="Send" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```